# Passing a char array by value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have problem with passing a char array by value to a `priority_queue`. I want to pass a unique value to the constructor, but I can only assign the type in the priority queue to `char*`. This causes a problem since the value passed changes through each iteration in the algorithm and then all the values in the priority queue (since every element is a pointer to task). Here is a code sample:

```
 char task[100];
 char priority;
 pair<int, char*> temp;
 priority_queue< int, vector<pair<int, char*>>, compare> queue;
 printf("Define a priority and a task to be done (exit by pressing CTRL-D):\n\n");
 do {
    priority=getchar();
    if(isdigit(priority)){
      scanf("%s", task);
      temp=make_pair(atoi(&priority), task); //I want to pass by value here not by reference, is there any solution to this?
      queue.push(temp);
      printf("%i %s\n", temp.first, temp.second);
    }
 } while(priority != EOF);
```

Is there any way that I can assign a unique string to every element of the priority queue?

Comment: The C++ solution: pass a `string` or `vector<char>` by value. The C solution: `struct foo { char task[100]; };` and pass that struct by value.

Comment: Just use `make_pair(..., std::string(task))` and change the related types accordingly.

Comment: Ok. I get it, this is a solution to the problem. Using char[] only is not a option at all in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment to question suggests you can wrap `char [100]` and `int` to new type (since `pair<>` gives poor abstraction). 
Another option is to use `std::string`, `std::vector<char>`, `std::array<char, 100>` instead of char[100].

PS: call to `atoi(&priority)` might fall because `atoi` expects null-terminated C-string, not a pointer to single character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `std::array<char,100>` I guess, but your current vector type *requires* a dynamically allocated string.

Do you want to force every element of your vector to be more than 100 bytes, however long the string?